# SQL Server connect from another computer to my database

Tags: sql-server

Hi all I installed SQL Server and from the localhost it works in my project however when I tried to access database from another computer It gives `0x80131904` exception. I couldn't find the reason what might be the solution?

Comment: You need a lot more information for this to be a question that can be answered.

Comment: That's an "Invalid Object Name" error.  You need to show the code that you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried connecting by specifying the port number as well? Something like,

1. YourServerName,1433
2. YourServerName\YourInstanceName,1433

I have assumed it is on the default port. If not change 1433 with appropriate port number and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is enabled for tcp/ip connections and that your computer does not block the SQL server port. Also make sure that you enable the proper authentication methods, ie SQL server auth, integrated, etc.